# remote redux devtools stopped working

Tags: react-native, redux, remote-debugging, redux-devtools

This question has been asked before but I cannot find a working solution so I'm taking the liberty to show my code in case I am missing something. I have a react native app and using redux. I have been using remote-redux-devtools for two months on this project now, but the tool stopped working all of a sudden. I receive a "SocketProtocolError" in the console and will paste that below as well as my code.

Redux store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "remote-redux-devtools";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "../../State/reducers/index";

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({ realtime: true });

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

In my package.json file I am using "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.13"

This is the error I get in the console.[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same error when debugging an app on my phone by running:

```
adb reverse tcp:5678 tcp:5678
```

to allow the phone to connect to the devtools. Adjust the port number if using a different one. If you're running the app in an emulator on your computer, this probably won't help.